# asp.net MVC 3 Error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

i've a AccountController like this

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult MyProfile(string userEmail)
    {
        UserManager um = new UserManager();
        UserProfile user = new UserProfile();
        user = um.GetUserDetail(userEmail);
        return View(user);
    } 
 }
```

i've  UserManager.cs  Like this

```
public class UserManager
{
    private ToLetDBEntities TLE = new ToLetDBEntities();
     public UserProfile GetUserDetail(string uemail)
    {
        var userDetails = TLE.users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.email_add == uemail);

        UserProfile up = new UserProfile();
        up.cellno = userDetails.cellno.Trim();
        up.email_add = userDetails.email_add.Trim();
        up.name = userDetails.name.Trim();
        up.password = userDetails.password.Trim();

        return up;
    }
}
```

When i'm debugging it gives error like

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   Null Reference Exception was Unhandled by User

At the line

```
up.cellno=userDetails.cellno.Trim();
```

Of the `GetUserDetails` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error suggests that you don't have a `userDetails` instance, so you can't get the `cellno` property.

Are you sure that `TLE.users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.email_add == uemail)` is returning something? If you put a breakpoint on the line that gives you the error, then you can check what the value of `userDetails` is - it's probably null.

Comment: Yes, userDetails is null.can you help me in query please... @LordSauce

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this query isn't returning anything:

```
TLE.users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.email_add == uemail);
```

The `FirstOrDefault` method won't give any kind of indication if no record is returned.  The `OrDefault` part specifies this behavior.  For any given return type, it will return the "default" for that type if no record is found.

For reference types (which yours is), the default is `null`.  So this call would result in exactly that exception:

```
userDetails.cellno.Trim();
```

Since `userDetails` is `null` then it can't access a `cellno` property, hence the exception.

It's also *possible* in your case that `userDetails` *isn't* `null` but that the `cellno` property on it *is*.  It's less likely, but possible.  Looking at the runtime value while debugging would tell you if that's the case.

If `userDetails` is `null`, check your query conditions.  Maybe the `users` collection has nothing in it?  Maybe there are no records which match your `x.email_add == uemail` condition?  (This is likely.)

If `cellno` is `null` then you'll want to check how that object is built, what the data in the database looks like, etc.  Either way, you're not getting back the data you expect.  The issue is in the data you're accessing.

Comment: Thanks David. I've changed the query into :  var userDetails = TLE.users.Single(x => x.email_add == uemail); it gives error: "Sequence contains no elements"

Comment: @AwladLiton: That means the query isn't returning any results, as I'd suspected.  It would appear that there are no `users` where the `email_add` equals the `uemail` value being passed to id.  Have you checked in the data to see if the record you're looking for exists?